# Android Camera - Save image into a new folder in SD Card

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a very simple APP which at the moment takes a picture and then saves the image. The problem at the moment is that for some reason i cannot find where the image is being saved to on the phone.

The finished outcome with what i am trying to do is when a picture is took the image then gets saved into a new folder that has been created on the SD Card, but if the folder does not already exist it will have to be made (automaticlly) before the image can be saved.

I have tried to use the answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402378/how-to-save-image-captured-with-camera-in-specific-folder) but cannot seem to incoporate it without getting the error `imageIntent cannot be resolved`

**EDIT: Image now saving into SD Card and creating folder but overwriting the pervious image I need it to save multiple images if any one has any suggestions code has been updated**

This is a snippet of my code:

```
PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*Bitmap bitmapPicture 
            = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);  */


        int imageNum = 0;
        Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Punch");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
        String fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
        File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
        while (output.exists()){
            imageNum++;
            fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
            output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
        }
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
        imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);


        OutputStream imageFileOS;
        try {
            imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);
            imageFileOS.write(arg0);
            imageFileOS.flush();
            imageFileOS.close();

            Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, 
                    "Image saved: ", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        camera.startPreview();
    }};
```

**EDIT**

Code has been updated to now save multiple images in a new folder created on SD Card.

Comment: What is "image" in ` Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save multiple image. you did one mistake every time when you are capturing the photo the folder is recreating again and again.

so you have to check whether the folder is already exist or not. you have to add only one line of code

```
if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {
imagesFolder.mkdirs();
}
else { //do nothing}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm purely **GUESSING** you forgot the necessary code from the question part of what you linked to.

The question has the following line at the very top:

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

If you just copied the code from the answer, then you would have that error because the code in the answer does not contain the instantiation of `imageIntent`.

Let me know if you need anything further or if I'm just totally wrong.

**UPDATE** (regarding image being overwritten):

You are currently using `"image_001.jpg"` as the string that represents the image name.
Set a variable within your Class `int imageNum = 0;`
Then you need to use a while loop and increment the image number - or you can create a different name for the image based on the time - that is another way to do it.

```
String fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
while (output.exists()){
    imageNum++;
    fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
    output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
}
//now save the file to the sdcard using output as the file
```

The above code - while not tested personally - should work.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out stupid mistake ;). I have just updated the question if you could take a look, it is now overwriting the prevoious image each time i take a new one.

Comment: Yes. The code I posted above should replace how you are currently creating the file with `File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");`. In your class body (like outside of any methods), you must put `int imageNum = 0;`, and then the code that I posted above should work. If that doesn't fix it, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

```
try {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
     + File.separator + "Your Floder Name"+ File.separator);
   root.mkdirs();
   sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
   startCameraActivity();
  } catch (Exception e) {

   Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   finish();
  }

 }

 protected void startCameraActivity() {



  Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
  startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 101);


 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if(requestCode==101 && resultCode==-1)
  {
   try
   {
    Uri outputFileUri= data.getData();
    selectedImagePath=getPath(outputFileUri);


   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
    Log.v("OnCameraCallBack",ex.getMessage());


   }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i have updated my question, i managed to get it saving to a new folder on the SD Card

Comment: this doesn't work in android 4.4.  the intent in onActivityForResult is null. Did something change in Android?