# How to store an image in a subfolder in a Sdcard in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-sdcard

I want to store my images in an sdcard subfolder. I have done the following but my images are not getting stored in the subfolder.How can I save my images in the subfolder?
My codes are as follows:

```
 final File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Wallpapertask/");
 wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
 myImageView1.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
 BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)myImageView1.getDrawable();
 Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
 File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "test2.png");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Camera - Save image into a new folder in SD Card](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588838/android-camera-save-image-into-a-new-folder-in-sd-card)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I save my images in the subfolder?

Your code does not save any images. You can use [the `compress()` method on `Bitmap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) to write a `Bitmap` to an `OutputStream`.

Also note that you should not be hardcoding paths, like `/sdcard/Wallpapertask`, as [that path will not work on all devices or for all users](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).