# Android Save Camera Image in Custom Folder

Tags: android, camera, save, directory, image

I know this question may seem repetitive as compared to a few other questions on here [How to save image captured with camera in specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402378/how-to-save-image-captured-with-camera-in-specific-folder)[like this] but I am still having trouble.  What I'm trying to do is make an app that after you take a picture with the camera, the image will be saved into a new folder (titled after the app name).  I am seeing that the folder was created, but the images don't seem to be inserting into them.  The following is some of my code where I believe I'm screwing up.  Any help out there would be a big help.  Thank you!

```
  camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(i, cameraData); 
            }
        });


    } 

    private void saveToFile(String message) throws Exception {
        String filePath = getFilesDir()+"";
        File file = new File(filePath + "/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA/Wardobe");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        out.write(message.getBytes());
        out.close();
        saveImage(filePath, "/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA/Wardobe/image.jpg", bmp);
        if(battleborn != null) {
            saveImage(filePath, "sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA/Wardrobe/image.jpg", bmp);
        } 

    }
    public void saveImage(String path, String dir, Bitmap image) {
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + dir);
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close(); 
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage) ?

Comment: Do not hard code the sdcard path. Use Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using this

```
File file = new File(Environment
    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
    + File.separator
    + "/your_folder_name/" + ".png");

FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
  fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
  if (fos != null) {
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
    fos.close();
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add permission to your mainfest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still struggling with this.  I did have the permission in the manifest (I did something right!) but where do I need to place your suggestion, and do I need to replace any of my featured code?  I tried adding it on to both the SaveToFile and saveImage methods, as well as replacing that code I had for each of those but something is still not clicking.

Comment: Have a look at this article (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media). It also explains how to save image to sdcard.

Comment: Thank you!  I got it going a few days back, thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this before calling the Camera intent

```
Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/flashCropped.png"));
camera.putExtra("output", uriSavedImage);
startActivityForResult(camera, 1);
```